# Is it possible to represent a WF4 wizard flow in a treeview or breadcrumb?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I am thinking of representing a Wizard Workflow, implemented in WF4, in a treeview or breadcrumb widget in MVC. The idea is that this will enable the user to  navigate across a workflow easily. The slight issue is that one would be showing just the "route travelled thus far" through any conditional gates. Obviously the XAML has the complete workflow, not the travelled one. Note sure if WF4 has this data stored anywhere. Not sure if this is possible?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a custom TrackingParticipant extension that records the executed activities in a workflow into a database, which your MVC app can read and display from.